# Bijection between multisets and directed animals?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multisets, polyomino

The number of directed animals (aka polyominoes) of size $n$ ([A005773](https://oeis.org/A005773)) is enumerated by the generating function $$\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt\frac{{1+z}}{{1-3 z}}\right).$$
This
generating function also enumerates the number of $n$-element multisets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ containing no pair of consecutive integers (e.g. $111, 113, 133, 222, 333$ for $n=3$).

The first few numbers in the sequence are
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 13, 35, 96, 267, 750, 2123, 6046, 17303, 49721.$$
Is there a good bijection between the two combinatorial classes?

---

This question is now resolved in [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v27i2p10).

Comment: You might want to post your paper as an *answer* to this question and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is now resolved in [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v27i2p10).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the second interepretation, but it seems natural enough.  I recall [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196885888900176) by Gouyou-Beauchamps and Viennot, which gives a bijection between directed animals and certain lattice paths.  The latter tend to be much easier to work with, so if you really need the bijection try to related these paths with the multisets.  Good luck!